# Question about selecting rows and columns from a DataFrame (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm following this [tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html) to select specific rows and columns from a DataFrame.

The tutorial example shows that you can use: `adult_names = titanic.loc[titanic["Age"] > 35, "Name"]`

to obtain:

`1     Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...`

`6                               McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J`

`11                             Bonnell, Miss. Elizabeth`

`13                          Andersson, Mr. Anders Johan`

`15                     Hewlett, Mrs. (Mary D Kingcome)`

`Name: Name, dtype: object`

However, if I want to access Miss. Elizabeth Bonnell, I'd have to use adult_names[11] (even though she's the 3rd name older than 35).

Is there a way to populate an array with these values so that the first name would be in adult_names[0], the second name would be in adult_names[1], the third name would be in adult_names[2], etc.?

Comment: USe `adult_names = titanic.loc[titanic["Age"] > 35, "Name"].tolist()` or `adult_names = titanic.loc[titanic["Age"] > 35, "Name"].to_numpy()`

Answer (score 0):

do you want something like this ?

```
adult_names = list(titanic.loc[titanic["Age"] > 35, "Name"].values)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also just use `adults_name` and use the `iloc`. `adult_name[11]` is the same as `adult_name.iloc[2]`. `iloc` is indexing by position.